# Texto não aparece na aplicação land/activity.main no Android Studio 2.2.2

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação na versão land do android land/activity.main  e coloquei uma imagem, e dois textos um com o nome Donald Knuth e outro um texto mas ao executar a aplicação mobile ele só aparece a imagem e o nome Donald Knuth e não aparece o texto explicativo, aparece uma palavra "Personality"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
tools:context="com.example.tulio.myapplication.MainActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/knuth_b"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="59dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNome2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Donald Knuth"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="31dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="280dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/donald"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="230dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="59dp" />
</ScrollView>

<![CDATA[

(Color.parseColor("#BABABA")); />

]]>
</LinearLayout>
```

Minha aplicação como era para estar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como esta

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está parecendo é que você tem dois arquivos de *strings*. Porque em um a linguagem está em inglês, já o outro está em português. Verifique em seus *resources* e insira o texto exatamente nas chaves devidas.

Basicamente isso:

***values***/strings.xml

```
<string name="donald">Texto que quero mostrar</string>
```

***values-en***/strings.xml

```
<string name="donald">Text that I want to show.</string>
```

Comment: então no caso eu tenho que criar uma string name com um nome pra cada, exemplo <string name="portugues">Texto que quero mostrar</string>  <string name="ingles">Text that I want to show.</string> e chamar  a string chamada portugues ?

Comment: @FelipePatrocinio não cara! Parece que já tem o diretório criado com as duas linguagens. Verifique se há o values e algum outro.

Comment: era isso mesmo man obrigado pela ajuda, tinha um values escrito Personality, obrigado pela ajuda